# .NET programmatically locate text box in ActiveX control, modify its text and submit it

Tags: .net, automation, activex, adobe-reader

I have an ActiveX control (Adobe PDF Reader) with a toolbar. This control doesn't expose some functions available through toolbar (mainly search function). I'm looking for a way to programmatically locate Search field on the toolbar, enter the text and invoke search (equivalent of pressing Enter in this field).
What's most accurate way to make that? Found a solution based on System.Windows.Automation namespace, but couldn't get it to work correctly.

Thanks.

Here's the code I tried:

```
Dim pdfElement As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(AxAcroPDF1.Handle)
Dim condition As New AndCondition(New OrCondition(New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text)), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsTextPatternAvailableProperty, True))
Dim ac As AutomationElementCollection = pdfElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condition)

For Each element As AutomationElement In ac

    If element.Current.Name = "Find" Then
        element.SetFocus()
        SendKeys.Send("TESTSEARCH")
    End If

Next
```

Comment: What couldn't you get it to do?  Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as you previous question.  The retail automation interface has the FindText() method.  I already gave you the link to the API documentation.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your answer. With that type of automation, will each user of my application need to purchase retail version?

Comment: No idea what the licensing terms are.  Surely you'll find that at adobe.com somewhere.  You're a bit too stingy to do it for you.

Comment: I'm not worried about licensing terms right now, I'm wondering if it's technically possible to use full automation interface without forcing each user to purchase Adobe software.

Comment: Whether you can redistribute the retail runtime has *everything* to do with licensing terms.

Comment: Hmmm... If that's permitted, any hint which files should be redistributed to make that possible?

Comment: I've downloaded full Acrobat version. Which COM should I reference instead of AcroPDF.DLL to use previously inaccessible methods (e.g. FindText)?